# Spreadsheet doesn't open on the cell active during save

Tags: cells

No matter what cell is active when I save this one particular worksheet, it always opens on cell N124.  Other worksheets work fine, they open on the cell that was active when I saved them.  Any thoughts?  I use Version 2009 (Build 13231.20390 Click-to-Run).

Comment: Two things:  (1) do a full repair of Office and then (2) See if File Open discloses a corrupt file. Failing that, there are commercial Excel file repair services you can consider.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As your question does not specify exactly what resolution you are seeking, here is a workaround to explicitly define what sheet/cell your workbook should focus to on open:

- Obtain a hyperlink to your workbook (this can be done through the Share function, or by referencing the file's UNC path, etc).
- Create a shortcut, e.g., an .lnk file, with which you plan to access the file (can skip this step if not accessing locally).
- Append the following query string to your URI:

```
    &activeCell=SheetName!CellNumber
```

...where `SheetName` is the name of your worksheet and `CellNumber` is the cell address you wish to have Excel focused upon.

Comment: My resolution would be to have workbook open on the cell that was active when I saved it.  I am using this worksheet to track things by date.  It keeps opening in the April area and I am trying to enter in the current week.  Just a lot to scroll through, and I was wondering what I changed to make it lock onto this one cell.

Comment: It's something I did at the workbook level.  I copied the sheet to a new workbook and it works fine.